# Вопрос об обособлении «спектра», следующего за обобщающим словом

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый вечер!

Предположим, есть предложение:

> Я люблю любые фрукты: абрикосы, бананы, яблоки и т. д.

Здесь с пунктуацией всё ясно: после слова ***фрукты*** ставится двоеточие.

А если после обобщающего слова стоят не однородные члены, а «спектр» (как правильнее это назвать?), например:

> Я люблю любые фрукты: от груш до ананасов.

или

> Я люблю любые фрукты: начиная от груш и заканчивая ананасами.

Какой знак препинания ставится после обобщающего слова в этом случае? Тоже двоеточие, или запятая, или тире?

Answer (score 2):

```
    А если после обобщающего слова стоят не однородные члены,
    а «спектр» (как правильнее это назвать?), например:
    Я люблю любые фрукты: от груш до ананасов.
```

Вы правы,это не однородные члены и не обобщающее слово.Я люблю любые фрукты от груш до ананасов.Это обычное несогласованное определение.Фрукты какие? от груш до ананасов. И **обычно** оно **не обособляется**.Несогласованные определения, выраженные косвенными падежами существительных(чаще с предлогом), обособляются, если подчёркивается выражаемое ими значение: Пятеро, без сюртуков, в одних жилетках, играли...(Гончаров.)

Таким образом, если Вы захотите подчеркнуть, то обособите или запятыми, или тире. Я бы выбрала тире, так как определение стоит в конце предложения и имеет уточняющее значение(любые - более широкая характеристика, а дальше ограничивается рамками от...до...)

Я люблю любые фрукты, начиная от груш и заканчивая ананасами.- Это **предложный оборот со значением уточнения**, поэтому обособляется запятыми, не обособлялся бы, если бы  предлог «начиная с» в буквальном смысле указывал на время, дату начала чего-либо (при этом слово «начиная» обычно можно опустить).

Кстати, предлог всё-таки "начиная с...", а не "начиная от..." -нарушение нормы.

Comment: `Кстати, предлог всё-таки "начиная с...", а не "начиная от..." -нарушение нормы.` — да нет, это вполне вариант нормы. В словаре Ожегова, словаре Лопатина и у Розенталя они приводятся как равноправные.

Comment: 1) [Ожегов](http://enc-dic.com/ozhegov/Nachinat-17817.html)
2) [Лопатин](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D1%82&all=x)
3) [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=185#pp185)

Answer (score 1):

**Я люблю любые фрукты: от груш до ананасов**. При такой структуре предложения  пояснительная интонация и двоеточие обычно сохраняются. Но: Любые фрукты, от груш до ананасов, очень полезны (обособление запятыми).

**Я люблю любые фрукты, начиная от груш и заканчивая ананасами.** Обособление подобных предложных оборотов со значением включения делается с помощью запятых.

Примеры: Но теперь у нас очереди за всем, **начиная от мяса и ботинок и кончая спичками и солью.** [Егор Гайдар. Гибель империи (2006)] Он последние полгода беспрестанно мелькал на экранах телевизоров, рекламируя самые разные товары: **от автомобилей до замороженных продуктов.** [Игорь Варламов. Какой футбол им не нужен // «Огонек», 2014]

Comment: *При такой структуре предложения пояснительная интонация и двоеточие обычно сохраняются* - правалом не поделитесь? Или хотя бы примерами. Вы же пишете "обычно", значит должны быть.

Answer (score 1):

На мой вкус здесь всё-таки нужно тире. 
Само по себе правило звучит недвусмысленно, двоеточие ставится после обобщающего слова, ***только*** если дальше идет перечисление. Про диапазон (или как там его назвать) никаких упоминаний в правилах нет.

Согласна, если рассуждать по аналогии, хочется обобщить и на случай диапазона, такая пунктуация не будет противоречить духу закона, но по его **букве** такое невозможно.

К сожалению, очень трудно найти примеры оформления в авторитетных источниках (сама по себе идея обобщающего слова при диапазоне значений необычна). У Sybilla примеры, как легко видеть, совсем не на этот случай. Но тире - такой знак, что его можно подставить почти везде как интонационный, даже вместо законного двоеточия в отдельных случаях, а уж когда это двоеточие само по себе сомнительно, тире - лучший выбор.

***Я люблю любые фрукты - от груш до ананасов.***

Ну нормально же смотрится, нет?

***Я люблю любые фрукты, начиная от груш и заканчивая ананасами.***

Здесь согласна. Структура описывающей диапазон части куда более напоминает обособляемый оборот, поэтому ни двоеточие, ни даже тире пониманию не способствовали бы. Запятая лучше, хотя тире, полагаю, всё-таки тоже возможно.

Comment: В данном случае мы имеем  пояснительное значение, которое является основным для двоеточия,  поэтом о "сомнительном" двоеточии говорить не приходится. Тире здесь также ВОЗМОЖНО, так как оно может заменять двоеточие, но при этом придаёт ряду (или словосочетанию)  ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНОЕ значение. При двоеточии основное внимание уделяется ряду, а в случае тире - это дополнительная информация (авторский выбор). Интонация двух вариантов такова: понижение тона делается в обоих случаях, но для двоеточия характерно неполное понижение голоса и более длительная (предупредительная) пауза.

Comment: @Sibylla  *В данном случае мы имеем пояснительное значение,*  - В каком из двух? И почему "пояснительное"? Вообще я не понимаю смысла ваших возражений. Двоеточие вы же признали ***правильным*** в своем ответе, с чем ***я не могу согласиться***.

Comment: 1) В современном языке двоеточие и тире могут заменять друг друга, только в отдельных случаях можно поставить только тире или только двоеточие (это, наверное,  понятно). 2) Слово "любой" имеет неопределенное значение, поэтому последующий текст ПОЯСНЯЕТего, раскрывает его содержание (это о ПОЯСНИТЕЛЬНОЙ функции). Итак, мы можем использовать тире или двоеточие, авторский выбор. Ну а семантические и интонационные особенности такого выбора  Вас, по-видимому, не интересуют, поэтому еще раз объяснять не буду.

Comment: Ну и что? Это как-то объясняет хотя бы вашу рекомендацию ставить двоеточие в вашем ответе - и возмущение этим же двоеточием (которое я назвала сомнительным), в моем ответе? Я совсем перестаю вас понимать, когда вы начинаете цитировать разные правила до кучи, забыв ответить на прямой вопрос.

Comment: Не надо называть двоеточие сомнительным (это неправильно), так как пояснительная функция - это основная функция двоеточия.  Моя рекомендация  (выбор двоеточия или тире) не является единственной, он допускает варианты, передающие разные смысловые оттенки. (Вы эти оттенки смысла и интонации не усматриваете). И правила я не цитирую, а просто пытаюсь объяснить фонетические и грамматические основы правописания, но Вам это не интересно. Поэтому  не стоит нам тратить время на подобные комментарии.

Comment: Вы совсем запутались. Комментируете в данном случае **Вы**. Мой ответ. И никак не можете сформулировать, в чем претензия. Если Вам не нравиится только слово "сомнинтельное", то я оставляю без подобное без внимания, ибо смысл, который я вкладываю разъяснен вполне, а ваши претензии субъективны, да и не принципиально это, как назвать.  Объяснений же, почему тут Вы некое "пояснительное значение" увидели и что их этого следует, я не дождалась.